# Python way to work with HDFS

Tags: python, hdfs

I have an HDFS directory with a huge number of files. When I trying to enter the directory via Web interface, a browser hangs. When I trying to list files via command line (`hadoop fs -ls /user/loom/many_files_dir/`) I get

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
        ......
```

I hope there is some python way to enumerate files in directory (or maybe other script language). Could you tell me about it?

Comment: In this case, I'd use Java API. There is no native Python API afaik. Other alternative is libhdfs, but it's also built on top of Java.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use snakebite http://snakebite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client.html#snakebite.client.Client.ls

```
client = snakebite.client.Client(host, port=8020)
list(client.ls(["/user/loom/many_files_dir/"]))
```

This talks directly to the namenode to get the listing, without invoking a local JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You may now be interested in the new python-hdfs interactor here: http://hdfs3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
hdfs = HDFileSystem(host=host, port=8020)
hdfs.ls("/user/loom/many_files_dir/")
```

Comment: Your other answer was good; it included a usage example, which would be of some use even if the link died. This answer could be improved with a similar example.

Comment: I have answered your comments. Anything else?